# Creating a thread from a method of an object

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

How is it possible to make a thread running the loop function of a TCP server instance in the example shown [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html).

**tcpserver.py**
    import SocketServer

```
class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    The request handler class for our server.

    It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
    override the handle() method to implement communication to the
    client.
    """

    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
        print self.data
        # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
        self.request.sendall(self.data.upper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)

    # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
    # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
    server.serve_forever() # <== make a thread for serve_forever()
```

I've tried adding the following code and running **server_forever()** in a thread but execution doesn't get over its invocation.

```
 from threading import Thread, Lock
 server_thread = Thread(target=server.serve_forever())
 server_thread.start()
 print "Execution doesn't get to this point"
```

How can I launch **server_forever()** so that I may run code after its invocation?

It's also a bit strange that even if the file containing the server is invoked from a remote python module, execution still hangs when the server is run. For example, running:

```
import os

os.system("python /path/to/tcpserver.py")
print "Execution doesn't get here either"
```

produces the same results.

The code in the answers from the suggested duplicate question do not work for the above example.

Comment: The code is as suggested in the answers of the duplicate question but it doesn't work.

Comment: No, it is not, and it is exactly that difference which makes the difference here. In your code, and in the duplicate question, you put `()` after your reference to your method. `()` calls the method, returning its result. The answer shows and explains that if you just want a reference to the method, you should not call it.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Thanks :)